# jQuery: How to divide text-string in half and make one half in different color?

Tags: jquery

Hello Stackoverflow family :)

I'm in need of a simple jQuery script, but since I'm a beginner in jQuery yet.. Then I cannot figure this out myself :( And there is no such script yet or I just don't know the correct term to search.

Idea is very simple. My designer designs h1 tags with two colors. For example: "Why use mysite.com?" then [mysite.com?] is with different color. I can see the technical solution as being triggered by $("h1.title") and the script would calculate how many words there are. Then divide by 2 and make one half different color with append container around them or something.

How to make this happen?

Kalle

Comment: Would it not be much easier to just wrap "mysite.com" in another tag with a different style applied to it?

Comment: Yes, been doing that until now. But issue is that, clients who will later use my CMS, might not know how to wrap them in different color and also might not care so much about it. So if this solution would be done by code, then my clients have to just mark the title with h1 or something. And the code would do the rest.

Comment: In that case, see my answer. It will work with strings of any length, so your clients can simply enter their text in an `h1` element, and the 2nd half of that string will be coloured differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use JavaScript to do this, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/Qpzsq/3/) for an example of a method for colouring the second half of the text of an element differently.

It does it by splitting the original string on spaces, determining the halfway point, and then rebuilding the string with a `span` (with whatever styles you like applied to it) around the second half:

```
$("h1").each(function() {
    var t = $(this).text();
    var splitT = t.split(" ");
    var halfIndex = Math.round(splitT.length / 2);
    var newText = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < splitT.length; i++) {
        if(i == halfIndex) {
            newText += "<span style='color:#ff0000'>";
        }
        newText += splitT[i] + " ";
    }
    newText += "</span>";
    $(this).html(newText);
});
```

I'm sure there's a quicker way of doing this, but this is the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Thanks, this is so far the best solution. However, I cant use id's. It must be either h1-tag or class triggered. Also, it has to work for multiple cases, like h1 and h2 on the same page.

Comment: You can query any element on the page. For example: `$("h1.title").html(newText);`

Comment: That looks fine to me! In your fiddle you use `h1` as the jQuery selector, which will select any `h1` element in the DOM. If you want to select `h1` elements with certain classes, you can use `$("h1.class1, h1.class2")`

Comment: So basically, I edited it a little. Its PERFECT now :) I finally got, what I wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/Qpzsq/5/ Maybe you can add the each part to your answer, because I want to give the code credit to you :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the `each` function. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread while searching for a way to spit a chunk of html into two parts, and thought I'd post my solution.

I used regex to return all top level html elements; this regex 'skips' nested elements because they are matched as the middle part of the top level elements.

It's then a simple divide, round and slice it up.

```
var result = str.match(/<(\w[\w\d]*)[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>/g);
var mid = Math.ceil(result.length / 2);
var part1 = result.slice(0,mid);
var part2 = result.slice(mid);
```

...or if you prefer 3 parts

```
var gap = Math.ceil(result.length / 3);
var part1 = result.slice(0,gap);
var part2 = result.slice(gap, gap*2);
var part3 = result.slice(gap*2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>
    <span style="header-color1">Why use </span> 
    <span style="header-color1">mysite.com?</span>
<h1>
```

And then style the `header-color1` and `header-color2` spans accordingly. This will look weird though, having a header in 2 different colors... not very good design imo but maybe your designer has a good idea, not sure.

This would not be overly difficult in jQuery but I think it would be a case of `overuse`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try smth like that:

```
//split h1 content by spaces


function color_header(str) {
    var words = str.split(' ');
    var words_num = words.length;

    if (words_num > 1) {
        var first_color_words = Math.floor(words_num / 2);
    } else {
        return str;
    }

    str = '<span class="color-1">';
    for (var i = 0; i < words_num; i += 1) {
        str += words[i];
        if (i === first_color_words - 1) {
            str += '</span><span class="color-2">';
        }
        if (i !== (words_num - 1)) {
            str += ' ';
        }
    }
    str += '</span>';
    return str;
}
```

Function receives string with title, and returnes html string like `<span class="color-1">part 1</span><span class="color-2"> part 2</span>`. If there is only 1 word in title - returns initial string